# Internal network issues between pfSense and Windows in VirtualBox

Tags: windows, networking, virtualbox, pfsense

I have three virtual machines running on Virtual Box. First one is Linux (pfsense) that's acting as a router with two network adapters one bridged and one set to the internal network. The other two vms are Windows 7 that are only connected to the internal network.

Now here is the issue, the Windows 7 machines can see each other, and can communicate. But neither of them can see the pfsense vm. pfsense also can't see them. I've double checked the internal network settings, IPs, subnets everything is correct. But whenever I try to ping the pfsense vm I get the usual message, Destination Host: unreachable. I've disabled Firewalls on the Windows machines, hoping that would fix the issue, nothing.. I can access the internet with the pfsense machine via the Bridged Adapter.

Network Setup:

```
pfsense (first vm):
- First Adapter: Bridged, DHCP, Promiscuous Mode: Deny
- Second Adapter: Internal Network, Static (192.168.0.254), Promiscuous Mode: Allow VMs

Windows 7 (second vm)
- Second Adapter: Internal Network, Static (192.168.0.15), Promiscuous Mode: Allow VMs

Windows 7 (third vm)
- Second Adapter: Internal Network, Static (192.168.0.30), Promiscuous Mode: Allow VMs
```

Virtualbox Version: 4.3.20

Comment: The most probable issue is that pfsense is denying ICMP requests by default. If you can change it to allow pinging, it could work.

Comment: As far as I am aware, pfSense blocks only ICMP request from the outside. Windows treats it as in the pfsense vm doesn't exist, and the other way around. Yet they are on the same network....

Comment: Im assuming they're in the same subnet as well? 192.168.0.0/24?

Comment: Using bridged on any of the clients might not what you need - you need three unique albeit simulated NICs and MACs before three simulated IPs?

Comment: @xR34P3Rx Yes they are all the same /24 on all machines. arch-abit I am using one bridged intergace only on the pfsense machine for the internet connection. I need to create another network, a virtual one, for some experiments. The network will have a Windows Server and a few Windows Clients, with a gateway that is the pfsense machine. Sorry for not clarifying earlier.

Comment: I'm not sure if this would have the same effect. But earlier back when i was doing something similar with a Debian server, the default nic that virtual box gives the vms wasn't working correctly, so i gave the vm an older nic and it worked fine. So perhaps you could see if that works for you tooi

Comment: Seems like the issue was in the Bridge segment. I changed to NAT and it started working.

Answer (score 1):

The Bridged Adapter on the pfsense machine was causing issues. Changed the first adapter on the pfsense machine from Bridged to NAT and that fixed the issue.